# How to consume the latest records from the topic using Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a Kafka Streams processor that consumes three topics and tries to merge (Joining operation) them on the key. After joining successfully, it does some aggregation and then pushes results to the target topic.
After the application runs for the first time, it tries to consume all data from those topics. Two of those topics use like lookup table, which means that I need to consume all data from the beginning. But one of those topics is my main topic. So I need to consume from the latest. But my application consumes all Kafka topics from the beginning. So I want to consume two topics from the start and one from the latest.
I'm using Spring Cloud Stream, Kafka Streams Binder. Here are my configs and some code snippets;

Application.yaml :

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition: processName;
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.processName.applicationId: myappId
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processName-in-0.destination: mainTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processName-in-0.consumer.group: mainTopic-cg
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processName-in-0.consumer.startOffset: latest
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processName-in-1.destination: secondTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processName-in-1.consumer.group: secondTopic-cg
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processName-in-1.consumer.startOffset: earliest
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processName-in-2.destination: thirdTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processName-in-2.consumer.group: thirdTopic-cg
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processName-in-2.consumer.startOffset: earliest
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processName-out-0.destination: otputTopics

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.replication-factor: 1
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.commit.interval.ms: 10000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.state.dir: state-store
```

Streams processor:

```
public Function<KStream<String, MainTopic>,
        Function<KTable<String, SecondTopic>,
                Function<KTable<String, ThirdTopic>,
                        KStream<String, OutputTopic>>>> processName(){
    return mainTopicKStream -> (
            secondTopicTable -> (
                    thirdTopicKTable -> (
                            aggregateOperations.AggregateByAmount(
                                    joinOperations.JoinSecondThirdTopic(mainTopicKStream ,secondTopicTable ,thirdTopicKTable )
                                            .filter((k,v) -> v.IsOk() != 4) 
                                            .groupByKey(Grouped.with(AppSerdes.String(), AppSerdes.OutputTopic()))
                                    , TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1)).advanceBy(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                            ).toStream()
                    )
            ));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points. When you have a Kafka Streams application using Spring Cloud Stream binder, you do not need to set `group` information on the bindings, just your `applicationId` setup is sufficient. Therefore, I suggest removing those 3 `group` properties from your configuration. Another thing is that any consumer specific binding properties when using Kafka streams binder needs to be set under `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.<binding-name>.consumer...`. This is mentioned in this [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_consumer_properties) of the docs. Please change your `startOffset` configuration accordingly. Also, look at the same section of the docs for an explanation of the semantics for using `startOffset` in Kafka Streams binder. Basically, the `start offset` property is honored only when you start the application for the first time. By default it is `earliest` when there are no committed offsets, but you can override to `latest` using the property. You can materialize the incoming `KTable`s as state stores and thus have access to all the lookup data.

Comment: That is a great explanation! It worked for my case. Really appreciate it! Also, I have a different problem. Do you have time to help me more? Here is question;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71023761/how-to-process-kafka-stream-using-the-custom-timezone