# How to process Kafka Stream using the custom timezone?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm trying to run my Kafka streams application under the "Asia/Istanbul" timezone. I'm not talking about the Timestamp extractor feature of Kafka streams. It means that I want to use windowing at different timezone. And after processing has been completed, I want to push windowStartime and windowEndtime using the timezone.

I tried to change the timezone environment using docker, changing the spring boot environment variables, but those didn't work.

My working set up is including Spring Cloud Stream, Kafka streams binder, and Docker.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the JVM timezone? Or mapping records from different zones into utc before windowing?

Comment: Yes, I did it. There is no problem with windowing because I transform the input data into the UTC. But the problem is the output of windowing. It gives me the date as a UTC. I solved temporarily by changing this date manually into the aggregation.